# How to design multi tagging in wide column with Cassandra?

Tags: tags, cassandra

I am designing a time-series database, with dynamic column. I was wondering, how to support tagging for each column.

Comment: Do you mean retrieve a column based on what it's tagged under?

Comment: Let's say a value is tagged by 'a', 'b', 'c'. We can search by tag with either 'a', 'b', 'c', all return the value.